# How to get rid of the filing 0 in the epc?

Tags: c#, rfid, zebra-printers, zpl

I'm using a simple c# function from the zebra example code to send my zpl to the printer. It works, but instead of writing my desired content into the epc of the rfid-tag it get filled up with unwanted "0"

This is the RFID-part of my sended zpl:

^RS8,25^RFW,H^FD00015004^FS

I send "00015004" but if I read the tag I get "000150040000000000000000" back. It's an Class 1 Gen 2 Tag

Already tried the ^RFW,E commend with ^RB, but that's converts it to hex with the same unwanted result.

How to erase/kill those additional 0?

full code:

```
            public void print(string ipAddress, int port) {
        try {
            //Printer Connection
            TcpClient client = new TcpClient();
            client.Connect(ipAddress, port);
            StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(client.GetStream());

            string ZPLString = "^XA" +
                                "^FXLabelSettings" +
                                "^MUD,300,300^PW970^LL270^LH0,0^JMA^FS^CVN^FS^CFD,54,25^FS" +
                                "^FXPrintContent" +
                                "^FO50,120^A0,100,150^FD00015004^FS" + //to print the number visible
                                "^FXRFIDSection" +
                                "^RS8,25^RFW,H^FD00015004^FS" + // to write into the epc and here is the Issue, the tag shows 000150040000000000000000 afterwards
                                "^XZ";

            //Printer Communication
            writer.Write(ZPLString);
            writer.Flush();
            writer.Close();
            client.Close();

        } catch (Exception ex) {
        }
    }
```

Comment: thanks, tried to simplify it and commented it

Comment: Can you just read back the 8 digits (4 hex pairs) you are interested in? Or write them at the end of the field instead of the beginning?  00 is null in hex, so I'm not sure you can get rid of them.

Comment: I could do both, but it's more an esthetic thing and the problem is the reading or more the processing part after the reading is not mine. To avoid that, I'm looking for a solution here

Answer (score 0):

I know I'm a bit late to the party but it might be useful if someone else stumbles over this post...

Try:

```
^RS8
^RFW,H,,,A^FD12345678^FS
```

When read with a RFID reader this will return the EPC code 12345678 without the trailing zeros.  For reference this was written to a tag using a Zebra ZQ511.

https://www.zebra.com/content/dam/zebra_new_ia/en-us/manuals/printers/common/programming/rfid3-pg-en.pdf